# maximum number of parallel processes using future package of R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

```r
library(future)
plan(multiprocess)
for (i in 1:20) {
  background_process <-  future({
     Sys.sleep(1000)
  })
}
# takes way too long to get here
```

I have a XEON 8 core, 16 thread CPU

I expected the above code to return control to the parent process in a matter of seconds, the time I expect it would take to create the 20 processes. But it took much longer than expected. So I inspected the number of R processes that my machine was running as this code was running. As it turns out, there are only 16 R processes running in the background.

So the question is, why does the code only able to create 16 processes and thus blocking the parent process while it waits to create the other 4 processes?

EDITED:

Ah, I see. Running `plan(multiprocess)` only creates 16 processes. How do I get it to create more then?

Answer (score 3):

If you read [*A Future for R: A Comprehensive Overview*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-1-overview.html) in a little detail, this is towards the middle:

> *"If nothing else is specified, all available cores on the machine will be utilized, cf. `parallel::detectCores()`. For more details, please see `help("availableCores", package = "future")`.*

So your **XEON 8 core, 16 thread CPU** is going to start with 16 processes.

I believe you can use something like this to get more:

```r
plan(multisession, workers = 17)
# I've seen this too, not sure when this is necessary
# plan(tweak(multisession, workers = 17))
```

Comment: My machine also has a Quadro RTX 4000. How do I get it to recognize that and create the processes using the thousands of cores in the GPU instead of the CPU?

Comment: `GPU != CPU`, they cannot be used interchangeably. See [CRAN Task View: High-Performance Computing](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html), under the section *"Parallel Computing: GPUs"*. Unfortunately, a GPU is a special-purpose CPU with a different instruction set. There are packages/libraries that natively take advantage of GPUs (e.g., [`tensorflow`](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/installation/gpu/local_gpu/)).